# Resize font size in Latex table when using \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}

Tags: tables, fontsize, resize

I am trying to increase the font size of the text in this Latex table to make it easier to read, while also fitting it to the page using \resizebox. How do I proceed?

Here is what I have already tried:

```
\documentclass[english]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[margin=.65in, includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{multirow}



\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}{cccccccccc}
  \hline
TX DG Customers & March 2019 & March 2018 & \% Change & March 2019 YTD & March 2018 YTD & \% Change & March 2019 Cumulative & March 2018 Cumulative & \% Change\\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Number of Applications}              & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2  & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{New Applications Capacity, kW}       & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2  & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Installed Capacity, kW}              & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2  & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Number of Meters Installed}          & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2  & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}}


\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}{cccccccccc}
NM DG Customers & March 2019 & March 2018 & \% Change & March 2019 YTD & March 2018 YTD & \% Change & March 2019 Cumulative & March 2018 Cumulative & \% Change\\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Number of Applications}              & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2  & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{New Applications Capacity, kW}       & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2  & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Installed Capacity, kW}              & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2  & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Number of Meters Installed}          & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2  & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}}

\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}{cccccccccc}
TX \& NM DG Customers & March 2019 & March 2018 & \% Change & March 2019 YTD & March 2018 YTD & \% Change & March 2019 Cumulative & March 2018 Cumulative & \% Change\\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Total Number of Applications}              & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2  & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{total New Applications Capacity, kW}       & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2  & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Total Installed Capacity, kW}              & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2  & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Total Number of Meters Installed}          & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2  & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: However you enlarge the font size, when you shrink the table to fit a width, the result will be the same.

Comment: never apply `\resizebox` to tables. It will always produce incompatible font sizes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have too long headers, but it's easy to shorten them by grouping.

Instead of three separate tables, you should have one, with various sections having a title for which I suggest italics a bit indented to the left.

Since the table is large, it makes sense to use `tabular*` and let TeX compute the intercolumn widths.

```latex
\documentclass[english]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[margin=.65in, includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{booktabs}



\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt} % let TeX compute the intercolumn space

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}\quad}lccccccccc}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{March}
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{March, YTD}
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{March, Cumulative} \\
\cmidrule{2-4}\cmidrule{5-7}\cmidrule{8-10}
& 2019 & 2018 & \% Change & 2019 & 2018 & \% Change & 2019 & 2018 & \% Change \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\itshape TX DG Customers} \\
Number of Applications              & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2  & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
New Applications Capacity, kW       & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2  & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
Installed Capacity, kW              & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2  & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
Number of Meters Installed          & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2  & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\itshape NM DG Customers} \\
Number of Applications              & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2  & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
New Applications Capacity, kW       & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2  & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
Installed Capacity, kW              & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2  & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
Number of Meters Installed          & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2  & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\itshape TX \& NM DG Customers} \\
Total Number of Applications        & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2  & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
Total New Applications Capacity, kW & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2  & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
Total Installed Capacity, kW        & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2  & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
Total Number of Meters Installed    & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2  & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I propose this code, which will spare you resizing box. It is based on `tabularx, makecell` and `booktabs` and uses the `small` fontsize:

```
\documentclass[english]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[margin=.65in, includefoot, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell, tabularx, booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\small
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\renewcommand{\cellset}{\renewcommand\arraystretch{0.3}}
\renewcommand{\cellalign}{bc}
\setcellgapes{2pt}\makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}X*{9}{c}@{}}
  \toprule
\centering TX DG Customers & \makecell[b]{\\ March 2019} & \makecell{\\ March 2018} &\makecell{ \%\\ Change} & \makecell{March 2019\\ YTD} & \makecell{March 2018\\ YTD}& \makecell{\%\\ Change} & \makecell{March 2019\\ Cumulative} & \makecell{March 2018\\ Cumulative} & \makecell{\%\\ Change}\\
\midrule
Number of Applications & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
New Applications Capacity, kW & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
Installed Capacity, kW & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
Number of Meters Installed & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
\bottomrule\addlinespace[3ex]
\centering NM DG Customers & \makecell{\\ March 2019} & \makecell{\\ March 2018} &\makecell{ \%\\ Change} & \makecell{March 2019\\ YTD} & \makecell{March 2018\\ YTD}& \makecell{\%\\ Change} & \makecell{March 2019\\ Cumulative} & \makecell{March 2018\\ Cumulative} & \makecell{\%\\ Change}\\
\midrule
Number of Applications & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
New Applications Capacity, kW & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
Installed Capacity, kW & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
Number of Meters Installed & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
\bottomrule\addlinespace[3ex]
\centering TX \& NM DG Customers & \makecell{\\ March 2019} & \makecell{\\ March 2018} &\makecell{ \%\\ Change} & \makecell{March 2019\\ YTD} & \makecell{March 2018\\ YTD}& \makecell{\%\\ Change} & \makecell{March 2019\\ Cumulative} & \makecell{March 2018\\ Cumulative} & \makecell{\%\\ Change}\\
\midrule
Total Number of Applications & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
total New Applications Capacity, kW & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
Total Installed Capacity, kW & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
Total Number of Meters Installed & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Never apply `\resizebox` to tables, as you found it always produces font sizes that are inconsistent with the rest of the docuemnt.

Perhaps something like

[image]

```
\documentclass[english]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[margin=.65in, includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}



\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cccccccccc}
  \toprule
 & \multicolumn{3}{c}{March}& \multicolumn{3}{c}{March YTD}&\multicolumn{3}{c}{March Cumulative}\\
 & 2019 & 2018 & \% Change & 2019 & 2018 & \% Change & 2019  & 2018 & \% Change\\
\cmidrule(rl){2-4}\cmidrule(rl){5-7}\cmidrule(rl){8-10}
TX DG Customers\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Number of Applications}              & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2  & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{New Applications Capacity, kW}       & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2  & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Installed Capacity, kW}              & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2  & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Number of Meters Installed}          & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2  & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
\midrule
NM DG Customers\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Number of Applications}              & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2  & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{New Applications Capacity, kW}       & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2  & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Installed Capacity, kW}              & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2  & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Number of Meters Installed}          & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2  & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
\midrule
TX \& NM DG Customers \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Total Number of Applications}              & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2  & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Total New Applications Capacity, kW}       & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2  & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Total Installed Capacity, kW}              & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2  & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Total Number of Meters Installed}          & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2  & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\noindent X\dotfill page width\dotfill X

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice table here!

Comment: Can you explain how you did resize the table to "text width" without increasing the font size (increasing the margin only)?

Comment: @ibilgen it was a long time ago, I guess I just adjusted `margin=.65in` until tex did not report the table as too wide